# Magento: Exclude a specific category from dropdown menu

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to exclude one specific category from a random menu I have. I have searched for answers and have found some potential solutions on here, but none of them worked.

This is what I currently have:

```
<?php
    $catID = $this->category_id;
    $catName = $this->category_name;
    $catType = $this->category_type;
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catID);
    $categories = $category->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail', 'description'))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
        ->addIdFilter( $category->getChildren() );
    $catIdEx = 38;
    $categories->getSelect()->join(array('cats' => 'catalog_category_product'), 'cats.product_id = e.entity_id');
    $categories->getSelect()->where('cats.category_id', array('neq' => $catIdEx));
    $categories->getSelect()->group(array('e.entity_id'));
    $categories->getSelect()->order('RAND()');
    $categories->getSelect()->limit(1);
?>
<?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
<div>
    <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl(); ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'catalog' . DS . 'category' . DS . $category->getThumbnail() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($category->getName()) ?>" class="boxedimage" />
    </a>
    <br />
    <h3>Spotlight <?php echo $catName ?></h3>
    <?php
        $sdesc = $category->getDescription();
        $sdesc = trim($sdesc);
        $limit = 230;
        if (strlen($sdesc) > $limit) {
            $sdesc = substr($sdesc, 0, strrpos(substr($sdesc, 0, $limit), ' '));
        }
    ?>
    <?php echo $sdesc."..."; ?>
    <div><a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl(); ?>" class="go">View <?php echo $category->getName(); ?> <?php echo $catType ?>...</a></div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your collection call looks pretty over the top for reasons im sure make sense for you, so I'll go with this - if you just want to exclude that category, add this to the foreach;

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
<?php if($category->getId() !== $catIdEx) { ?>
<div>
<!-- your other code here -->

</div>
<?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either. I left the coding I had. I also stripped the coding that was supposed to filter it out above.

Comment: http://www.steinjewelrycompany.com/fine-gifts-and-accessories

I only have 2 categories currently activated on Jewelry in the dropdown. You will see a Spotlight Designer on the right. Rolex should not show up at all and it still finds its way. Rolex is also Cat ID: 38. I checked to be sure I had the right ID many times.

Comment: sounds like your value for $catIdEx is incorrect.  within the foreach loop add <?php echo 'ID is: '.$category->getId(); ?> to make certain the one you are trying to exclude has the ID you think it does

Comment: ID is: 38

What I am getting when I placed that code in. For some reason, it doesn't want to hide 38.

Answer (score 0):

```
$excluded_category = array('20','4','6');
<?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
<?php if(!in_array($category->getId(),$excluded_category)) { ?>
<div>
<!-- your other code here -->

</div>
<?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Manoj. This does work, but not quite what I need it to do. The code is being run on a random script that chooses 1 category to highlight. It changes every time you refresh or go to a new page. Eliminating this one drops the entire element out. I just want it to be forgotten in the script so another one can replace it. If that makes sense.